# Angular charts embedded Legend not working with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, charts

So I'm working with [angular-charts](https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts/), and I'm loving it so far, but I'm having an issue with one thing.

I want to use ng-click on a link in the in the legend. The legend is embedded with HTML, and the link shows up correctly, but on click, it isnt doing the function. I have  basic set up in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zKCgAdTAUPOWHGZOsh7h) if anyone is willing to help.

Here is the legned config and the series data:

```
legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'right',
      htmlEnabled: true
    }

series: ['<a href="javascript:void(0) ng-click="testClick()";">Sales</a>', 'Income', 'Expense', 'Laptops', 'Keyboards']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in sample: double quote is missing after `void(0)`. But this won't work anyway.

First, their directive [has an isolated scope](https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts/blob/master/src/angular-charts.js#L1182), which means it doesn't know about `testClick` function from your controller's scope.

Second, labels contents are [rendered using `$sce.trustAsHtml`](https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts/blob/master/src/angular-charts.js#L1124), so they are "simple" HTML - AngularJS won't detect your `ng-click`.

I'd disable library's embedded legend and build it separately.